# Create dynamic templated message based on a list

Tags: java

this is easy in JavaScript.  Not sure how to do this in Java:

Here's the hash table that's sent into **displayItems**:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> items = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
items.put(0, "Soda");
items.put(1, "Candy");
items.put(2, "Fruit");
```

Now here's what I'm trying to do, create a message based on that list:

```
 public void displayItems(Hashtable<Integer, String> items) {
    String message = "Please specify an item: ";
    items.forEach((itemIndex, itemName) -> {
      message += `${itemIndex}: ${itemName},`;
    });
    outputStream.print(message);
  }
```

**What I want to end up with printed to the stream for *message* is this:**

```
"Please specify an item: 0: Soda, 1: Candy, 2: Fruit"
```

Comment: You got couple of answers that both produce the output you want. You waiting for something before you accept one?

Answer (score 2):

The other answer works but here is a standard solution if you want to keep your `displayItems` function and `Hashtable`.

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> items = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
items.put(0, "Soda");
items.put(1, "Candy");
items.put(2, "Fruit");
    
displayItems(items);

public static void displayItems(Hashtable<Integer, String> items) {
   String message = "Please specify an item: ";
   for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
       message += String.valueOf(i) + ": " + items.get(i);
       if(i+1 < items.size()) message += ", ";
   }
   System.out.println(message);
}
```

Output:

```
Please specify an item: 0: Soda, 1: Candy, 2: Fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Map<Integer, String> items = Map.of(
        0, "Soda",
        1, "Candy",
        2, "Fruit"
    );
    
    String s = items.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> String.format("%d: %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "Please specify an item: ", ""));
    System.out.println(s);
  } 
}
```

> Please specify an item: 1: Candy, 0: Soda, 2: Fruit

**Notes:**

1. The `Map` is created using Java 11 builder syntax, if you're using a lower version, you can update the code accordingly. Don't use `Hashtable`; it's been deprecated for decades now.
2. There's no guarantee that the items are going to be sorted according to the numeric indices. If that matters, add a `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))` before the `.map()`.

Comment: this is a kata, I'm using Java SDK 1.8